# get number of rows in a table

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

I would like to get the number of rows within a table. 
I have tried it in several ways(without any success) and finally I have tried it the following way:

```
  var _tableOfInterestsCount = wait.Until(x => x.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='gridBodyTable']/tbody")));
        var  _trs = wait.Until(x => x.FindElements(By.XPath(".//tr[@class = 'ms-crm-List-Row']")));
```

while debugging, I'm getting Count = 1 while there are 3 rows. for sure. 
All the 3 tr's have the same class.
in addition, there's even an attribute in this table says: `numrecords="3"`
and when using the following , again , I'm getting the value of 1 instead of 3.

```
var _tableOfInterestsCount = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='gridBodyTable']")).GetAttribute("numrecords"));
```

relevant HTML code:

```html
<table class="ms-crm-List-Data" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" rules="rows" morerecords="0" totalrecordcount="3" allrecordscounted="1" oname="10046" numrecords="3" tabindex="0" primaryfieldname="new_name" summary="foo" border="1" id="gridBodyTable" style="border-style:None;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <colgroup><col width="18px" class="ms-crm-List-CheckBoxColumn"><col width="302" name="new_name" class="ms-crm-List-DataColumn ms-crm-List-SortedColumn"><col width="127" name="createdon" class="ms-crm-List-DataColumn"><col></colgroup><thead><tr class="ms-crm-Hidden-List"><th scope="col" class="ms-crm-Hidden-List"></th><th scope="col" class="ms-crm-Hidden-List">שם</th><th scope="col" class="ms-crm-Hidden-List">created at</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr class="ms-crm-List-Row" oid="{5843AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}" otype="10046" otypename="new_contact_content" selected="false">
   <td class="ms-crm-List-NonDataCell" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="ms-crm-RowCheckBox" id="checkBox_{5843AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}" tabindex="0" title="1" style=" "></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding"><nobr class="gridcellpadding" title="name1"><a href="#" id="gridBodyTable_primaryField_{5843AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}_0" target="_self" title="name 1" class="ms-crm-List-Link" tabindex="0">name 1</a></nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding ms-crm-NumbersAndDates"><nobr class="gridcellpadding" title="20/02/2017 08:55">20/02/2017 08:55</nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell"><nobr class="gridcellpadding"></nobr></td>
  </tr><tr class="ms-crm-List-Row" oid="{5943AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}" otype="10046" otypename="new_contact_content" selected="false">
   <td class="ms-crm-List-NonDataCell" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="ms-crm-RowCheckBox" id="checkBox_{5943AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}" tabindex="0" title="3" style=" "></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding"><nobr class="gridcellpadding" title="3"><a href="#" id="gridBodyTable_primaryField_{5943AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}_1" target="_self" title="3" class="ms-crm-List-Link" tabindex="0">3</a></nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding ms-crm-NumbersAndDates"><nobr class="gridcellpadding" title="20/02/2017 08:55">20/02/2017 08:55</nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell"><nobr class="gridcellpadding"></nobr></td>
  </tr><tr class="ms-crm-List-Row" oid="{5A43AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}" otype="10046" otypename="new_contact_content" selected="false">
   <td class="ms-crm-List-NonDataCell" align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="ms-crm-RowCheckBox" id="checkBox_{5A43AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}" tabindex="0" title="9" style=" "></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding"><nobr class="gridcellpadding" title="9"><a href="#" id="gridBodyTable_primaryField_{5A43AB8E-39F7-E611-BE37-00155D47B163}_2" target="_self" title="9" class="ms-crm-List-Link" tabindex="0">9</a></nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell inner-grid-cellPadding ms-crm-NumbersAndDates"><nobr class="gridcellpadding">20/02/2017 08:55</nobr></td><td class="ms-crm-List-DataCell"><nobr class="gridcellpadding"></nobr></td>
  </tr></tbody>
 </table>
```

EDIT:
By the way, when there are 2 rows, the count is 0.
I even tried the following , but still getting the wrong adttribute's value:

```
 Dictionary<string, object> attributes = executor.ExecuteScript("var items = {}; for (index = 0; index < arguments[0].attributes.length; ++index) { items[arguments[0].attributes[index].name] = arguments[0].attributes[index].value }; return items;", _tableOfInterestsCount) as Dictionary<string, object>;
```

Comment: Could you share relevant HTML as well??

Comment: numrecords="3" vs. GetAttribute("numberrecords"), is that supposed to be different?

Comment: @drw85 sorry, fixed it. it should be numrecords, but it is not the issue :)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur did it.10x

Answer (score 1):

Why are you accessing your table by xpath when it has an Id?
you usually should do something like:

```
 var _tableOfInterestsCount =Driver.FindElement(By.Id("gridBodyTable"));
 List<IWebElement> _trs = _tableOfInterestsCount .FindElements(By.ClassName("ms-crm-List-Row")).ToList();
 int count=_trs.Count();
```

if this does not work please also share the rows HTML.

Comment: I have tried with ID as well..The solution provided is my 4th shot. I will share the rows as well

Comment: are you sure that you are using the same code? can you try to copy paste it? it should work

Comment: unfortunately , the count is still 1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
findElements(By.xpath(".//div/table/tbody/tr")).size()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the problem was I had to switch to different frame first and then locate the element.

```
_webdriverIE.SwitchTo().Frame(_webdriverIE.FindElement(By.XPath(".//iframe[@id='area_new_contact_new_contact_contentFrame']")));
```